Naming alkanes with two branches in symmetrical positions
When naming an alkane with two substituents (e.g. methyl and ethyl branches), the carbon atoms in the main chain need to be assigned to lowest numbers possible. In the example in this link, why is the name 3-ethyl-4-methylhexane and not 4-ethyl-3-methylhexane. Since both of these possible names minimises the numbers assigned to the two branches, why is the ethyl branch assigned a lower number than the methyl branch?

Also duplicate: Preference of locants in organic nomenclature
